# Oracle: "Process W000 submission failed with error = 20" after IP change

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

We have recently changed the Ip of our Oracle Server and since then we have noticed some random occurrences of ORA-12519 during connection.

The most common causes: max number processes reached and listener down are discarded.

After checking the alert log I found a lot of messages like this:

```
<msg time='2019-06-08T08:13:54.050-03:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='rdbms'
 msg_id='ksbsrv:3020:323864049' client_id='' type='ERROR'
 group='background_proc' level='8' host_id='myserver.com'
 host_addr='123.123.123.123' module='KTSJ' pid='24688'>
 <txt>Process W000 submission failed with error = 20
 </txt>
</msg>
```

I have changed the host_addr but '123.123.123.123' equals the old server ip.

These occurrences seem to be very close to the ORA-12519 problems.

How/where can I update this ip information?